# What kind of programming environment do you use to write your Windows-based Games?

Tags: development-environment

I've used XNA and Visual Studio 2005 integrated with Flash.  I'm curious to see what environments other people use and prefer.

Comment: I would be interested to know what you create your models/textures/art with.

Comment: I'd love to know how you integrate Flash with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed some cross-platform 2D games (Windows as well) and used C++ with [Geany](http://www.geany.org) and [SDL](http://libsdl.org).

I find SDL to be a great library to make casual games. Of course, if cross-platform means Windows and XBOX for you, then there are other libraries that might be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Same. XNA 2.0 in VS2005 or XNA 3.0 in VS2008.

I've also dabbled in darkGDK when I feel like some C++.

Comment: I'll have to check into darkGDK - I've not done C++ in 3 or 4 years, but it's where I got my start.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Although not Windows-specific, I have used [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/), which can use DirectX as a backend.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Dev-C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) and [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)

Answer (score 0):

At Flying Lab for Pirates of the Burning Sea we used Visual Studio 2005.  At Divide by Zero for  we use Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 with XNA 3.0 CTP is what I'm using at the moment. A lot of game development shops are still using VS05, however.